# CodeIgniter Error Reporting Difference between 1.7.x and 2.x

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, error-reporting

I have two identical Debian Squeeze servers running php 5.3.3-7+squeeze17, one running 1.7.x, the other 2.1.4.

On the 1.7 installation, when I call a controller method that calls an undefined model method, the page outputs:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Example_Model::get_series_and_products() in /opt/git/online_live/application/controllers/members.php on line 2549
```

However, on 2.1.4 there is no output at all. `echo` statements inserted before the undefined function output text, but statements after do not.

Both sites have php error_reporting set to -1 in their VirtualHost config, which seems to override the config.php defined ENVIRONMENT setting of development, which sets error_reporting to E_ALL.

Here's some extra code I'm using for output:

```
echo ini_get('error_reporting');
echo '<br>';
echo phpversion();
```

Which outputs the same on both:

```
-1  
5.3.3-7+squeeze17
```

So, it would not appear that anything else is trumping my error_reporting.

In application/config/config.php in 2.1.4 (where the error's not showing):

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 4; // All Messages
```

In 1.7 (where the error is showing):

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 0;
```

But I thought that setting was for the file system log that CI keeps and not inline errors.

phpInfo() reflects the same error_log values on both hosts:

```
error_log:              no value    no value
error_reporting:        -1          22527
```

What could be causing the difference?

Comment: what is your log level for both CI setups? (application/config/config.php for 2.1.X) also when you compare `phpinfo()` are you seeing error logging the same? In the end it is hard to say as we don't have much info to go on.

Comment: I thought if ini_get('error_reporting') was reporting -1, it wouldn't matter what was in config.php, but nonetheless I've added the log_threshold parameter above. Is that the parameter you're referring to?

phpInfo() for both yields the same values:

error_append_string: no value  
error_log: no value  
error_prepend_string: no value  
error_reporting: -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*EDIT:* This **does not** apply if your setting was set using `php_admin_value` or `php_admin_flag`. Thanks to jaydisc for enlightening me about this fact. The answer lay in the `display_error` directive, which governs the display of errors instead.

However, I am leaving the rest of the post here because based on the question title, this would be a possible answer if not for the `php_admin_value` setting.

### Error Reporting Difference between 1.7.x and 2.x

Regardless of your `error_reporting` settings, Codeigniter overwrites it in the `index.php`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

`The error_reporting() function sets the error_reporting directive at runtime. PHP has many levels of errors, using this function sets that level for the duration (runtime) of your script.`

This is as `error_reporting` belongs to a family of `ini_set` functions: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php, which **override** php directives for the duration of the script, including the php_admin_value.

For 1.7.x, (looking at old versions here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/downloads.html),

the first line of code in `index.php` is

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

, which enables errors no matter what (unless the setting is changed via the code later).

For 2.1.4, (https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1.4/index.php) it depends on the `ENVIRONMENT` constant:

```
/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * ERROR REPORTING
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Different environments will require different levels of error reporting.
 * By default development will show errors but testing and live will hide them.
 */

if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
        break;

        case 'testing':
        case 'production':
            error_reporting(0);
        break;

        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I'm using php_admin_value in the VirtualHost, so I will politely disagree, as that overrides any individual php file's directive. But regardless, shouldn't the error show up with E_ALL anyway?

Comment: @jaydisc I updated my answer to reflect the fact that `error_reporting()` overrides any server directives. Also, if you're concerned about the display of errors, then the `display_error` directive is also relevant. You should check your settings for that as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php disagrees with you: `Any directive type set with php_admin_value can **not** be overridden by .htaccess or ini_set().`. However, your idea to look at display_error was indeed correct. Once I set that using a php_admin_flag, all was well. Thank you. I'm a bit afraid to mark your answer as the right one because of the misinfo about php_admin_value though.

Comment: @jaydisc No misinformation was intended, I actually did not know that, thanks for the link! I've updated my answer further to reflect that as well.